# Python Multithreading - How to prevent None items from ending up in result - Concurrent Futures

Tags: python, multithreading, concurrency, threadpool

I am looking to scrape SSL data from a list of hostnames. Everything is working as expected, except that when the get_cert_data function returns None due to the absence of SSL cert or inability to connect to the host. The None value is appended to the certs_list either way. I am using a large list of 1 million hosts and I am expecting most of them to have no SSL certificate due to the nature of the data. Understandably I would like to save memory and not store 900K None values in a list. Thank you for taking the time to read this far! Bonus: Does it make more sense to use the domain name or hostname to obtain this data and why?

```
import concurrent.futures
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('hostnames.csv')
hosts_list = df['Host name'].tolist()

def get_cert_data(hostname):
    try:
        ctx = ssl.create_default_context()
        s = ctx.wrap_socket(socket.socket(), server_hostname=hostname)
        s.connect((hostname, 443))
        cert = s.getpeercert()
        issuer = dict(x[0] for x in cert['issuer'])
        issued_by = issuer['organizationName']
        if not "COMODO" in issued_by.upper():
            pass
        else:
            print(issued_by)
            return cert
    except Exception as e:
        pass

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers = 16) as pool:
    certs_list = list(pool.map(get_cert_data, hosts_list))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `pool.map` does not return the results. It returns an iterable of `Future` objects. Each one represents an operation to be executed. So, you have to filter of their results.

```
valid_certs = [cert.result() for cert in certs if cert.result() is not None]
```

Comment: Small misspelling there, it should say _valid_certs = [cert.result() for cert **in** certs if cert.result() is not None]_

Comment: Thank you @blue_note. Is 'cert' referencing the return value of get_cert_data? Its not 100% clear to me

Comment: @the cert is referencing the *future* (whenever it completes) return value of get_cert_data. See class `concurrent.futures.Future`

Comment: Sorry the thing I am getting confused with is for cert in certs. What is certs referencing?

Comment: @ezeekiel: sorry, I meant the `certs_list` variable obviously

Comment: @blue_note thats Ok I figured that much, but for some reason I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'result'